# Calculator output error

Tags: java, android, operators, calculator

I am trying Calculator code.

My design link https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrzRD.png

If my string s1 value = 2*5*7+1+4

What to do in this part of my code to get result in text view

```
s1 = (edt1.getText()+"");
                    ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String temp = "";
                    for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++) {
                        if (Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(j)) || s1.charAt(j) == '.') {
                            char c1 = s1.charAt(j);

                            temp = temp + String.valueOf(c1);

                        }
                        if (s1.charAt(j) == '+' || s1.charAt(j) == '-' || s1.charAt(j) == '*' || s1.charAt(j) == '/') {
                            buffer.add(temp);
                            temp = "";
                            buffer.add(String.valueOf(s1.charAt(j)));
                        }
                    }
                    buffer.add(temp);
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I just edited my code can u see my code @JoeC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatinating strings , use  below instead

```
button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(Interger.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString()) + Interger.parseInt(s7));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

your main problem is in this line `edt1.setText(edt1.getText() +s2);` and any  line like this , the (+) si not the calculation process put it is concatenation between two string so you must **make s2 int instead of string** and parse the text inside the edittext like this **Integer.parse(edt1.getText().tostring())** to the (+) will be calcaulation process between 2 number instead of being concatenation process